# What is "python3 -m pip install --upgrade"?

Tags: installation, python, pip

I've installed the package `github` with the command `python3 -m pip install --upgrade github.py` and now I can't uninstall it with `pip3 uninstall github` because it says it isn't installed. So if I didn't install the package what did I do?

```
❯ python3 -m pip install --upgrade github.py
Collecting github.py
  Downloading github.py-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (80 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 80 kB 2.5 MB/s
Collecting aiohttp
  Downloading aiohttp-3.7.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 8.0 MB/s
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.5
  Downloading typing_extensions-3.7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Downloading async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Downloading yarl-1.6.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (324 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 324 kB 7.8 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from aiohttp->github.py) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: attrs>=17.3.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from aiohttp->github.py) (19.3.0)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
  Downloading multidict-5.1.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (159 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 159 kB 19.2 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp->github.py) (2.8)
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, async-timeout, multidict, yarl, aiohttp, github.py
Successfully installed aiohttp-3.7.3 async-timeout-3.0.1 github.py-0.5.0 multidict-5.1.0 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3 yarl-1.6.3
```

Comment: Can you provide the log that was generated when you installed it?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant for the question. Maybe I should link it here in the comment?

Comment: All information must be contained in the question.  You shouldn't submit helpful relevant information in a comment.  I would presume github.py was installed here: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` is that the case?

Comment: I don't see it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is "python3 -m pip install --upgrade"?

This command uses the version of `pip`  associated with the `python3` command (Python installation) to install/upgrade a package to that particular Python installation.

> If I didn't install the package, what did I do?

You clearly installed the package(s):

`Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, async-timeout, multidict, yarl, aiohttp, github.py`

`Successfully installed aiohttp-3.7.3 async-timeout-3.0.1 github.py-0.5.0 multidict-5.1.0 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3 yarl-1.6.3`

At a guess, it seems possible that your `python3 -m pip` (`python3`) command and your `pip3` command are associated with separate Python installations on your system. Python allows this for isolation (so you can have one Python environment with one set of packages and manage those packages separately from another Python environment). If this is the case, `python3 -m pip` installed ex. `github.py` to an installation of Python which is *not* associated with your `pip3` command.

You should be able to uninstall `github.py` with something like `python3 -m pip uninstall github.py`. If you want to see what Python installation(s) `python3` and `pip3` reference, try running `which python3` and `which pip3` respectively.